# Html form submission button not working

Tags: php, html, forms, button

Well i have this code , if i remove the table content , the button is working ok , but when i am inserting it in the code , the button is not working at all ! Some help please !

```
<body>
<img style="POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 17px; Z-INDEX: 100; TOP: 17px" border="0" src="gogo.png" width="174" height="59"/> <img style="POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 8px; Z-INDEX: 100; TOP: 482px" border="0" src="kup.jpg" width="937" height="168"/><table cellpadding="0" width="456" border="0">
  <tbody>
              <form name="Register" method="post" action="register_details.php">
      <tr bgcolor="#0000ff">
        <td colspan="4">
          <div align="left">
            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
              <font color="#ffffff" size="2"></font>
            </font>
          </div>
          <strong>
            <font color="#ffffff" size="3" face="Arial,Helvetica">&nbsp;Potwierd&#378; informacje</font> <font color="#ffffff">:</font></strong> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="132">
          <div align="left">
            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
              <font size="2"></font>
            </font>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#0000ff">
          <div align="left">
            <strong>
              <font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Arial,Helvetica">&nbsp;Imi&#281; :*</font> </strong>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <input id="first_name" maxlength="30" size="35" name="first_name"/> </font>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#0000ff">
          <div align="left">
            <strong>
              <font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Arial,Helvetica">&nbsp;Nazwisko :*</font> </strong>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <input id="last_name" maxlength="30" size="35" name="last_name"/> </font>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#0000ff">
          <div align="left">
            <font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Arial,Helvetica">&nbsp;Nazwa firmy:</font> </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <input id="company" maxlength="30" size="35" name="company"/> </font>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#0000ff">
          <div align="left">
            <strong>
              <font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Arial,Helvetica">
                <div align="left">
                  <strong>
                    <font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Arial,Helvetica">&nbsp;Adres:*</font> </strong>
                </div>
              </font>
            </strong>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <input id="address" maxlength="50" size="35" name="address"/> </font>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#0000ff">
          <div align="left">
            <strong>
              <font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Arial,Helvetica">&nbsp;Miasto :*</font> </strong>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <input id="city" maxlength="25" size="35" name="city"/> </font>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#0000ff" height="19">
          <div align="left">
            <strong>
              <font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Arial,Helvetica">&nbsp;Kraj:*</font> </strong>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <select id="country" size="1" name="country"> <option value="usa">Wybierz swoj kraj</option> <option value="Polska">Polska</option> <option value="Niemcy">Niemcy</option> <option value="Francja">Francja</option> <option value="Wlochy">Wlochy</option> <option value=" ">-----------------------</option> <option value="Zjednoczone Królestwo">Zjednoczone Krolestwo</option></select> </font>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#0000ff" height="22">
          <div align="left">
            <strong>
              <font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Arial,Helvetica">&nbsp;Prowincja:*</font> </strong>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <input id="other_state" maxlength="15" size="8" name="other_state"/> </font>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#0000ff">
          <div align="left">
            <strong>
              <font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Arial,Helvetica">&nbsp;Kod pocztowy:*</font> </strong>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <input id="zip" maxlength="20" size="10" name="zip"/> </font>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#0000ff">
          <div align="left">
            <strong>
              <font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Arial,Helvetica">&nbsp;Numer telefonu:*</font> </strong>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">( <input id="phone_prefix" maxlength="3" size="5" name="phone_prefix"/> ) <input id="phone_number" maxlength="10" name="phone_number"/> </font>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#0000ff">
          <div align="left">
            <font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Arial,Helvetica">&nbsp;Fax:</font> </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">( <input id="fax_prefix" maxlength="3" size="5" name="fax_prefix"/> ) <input id="fax_number" maxlength="10" name="fax_number"/> </font>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#0000ff">
          <div align="left">
            <strong>
              <font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="Arial,Helvetica">&nbsp;E-mail:*</font> </strong>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <input id="your_email" maxlength="35" size="35" name="your_email"/> </font>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div align="left">
            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
              <font size="2"></font>
            </font>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;</font> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div align="left">
            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
              <font size="2"></font>
            </font>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;</font> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div align="left">
            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
              <font size="2"></font>
            </font>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div align="center">
          <input value="Kup Teraz" type="submit" name="Submit"/> <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></div>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    </form>
  </tbody>
</table></body>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? Maybe it's you PHP that's not working. Why don't you use some CSS in a external file?

Comment: this is the whole form , and at the end got the submit button that must do the action to register_details.php

Comment: i have in the code <table cellpadding="0" width="456" border="0"> closed at the end with </table> , without this , the submit button is working perfect , but with this table included , it's not working anymore

Comment: `@OP`. **2 upvotes** on `Mike W's` answer, and am sure it'll keep rising. ;-) *Count me in, why not(?).* **OOPS...4**, *I stand "corrected".*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't open a `<form>` in a `<tbody>` - it breaks the `<table>` syntax. Move the `<form>` tags right outside the `<table>`.

Comment: I learn something new every day. Even if it does come in bits & pieces.